# how can i add link to these box

Tags: html, css, href

i want to link each box to different link. whole box not only content or image so if user try to click any of these will be sent to the link applied .
i have tried putting a tag on these box but my box color changes and things go wrong.
need help pls

```css
.container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
}
.container .box{
    position: relative;
    width: 33.33%; /*Change Applied*/
    height: 500px;
    background: #ccc;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .box:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.container .box .thumb{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container .box:nth-child(odd) .thumb {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.container .box .thumb img{
    width: 100%;
}
.container .box .details{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #262626;
}
.container .box:nth-child(even) .details {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.container .box:nth-child(1) .details {
    background: #65214a;
}
.container .box:nth-child(2) .details {
    background: #fd3f41;
}
.container .box:nth-child(3) .details {
    background: #ffb539;
}
.container .box .details .content{
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% + 16px);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .box:hover .details .content{
    top: calc(50%);
}
.container .box .details .content h3{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="activity.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81z07Nvam1L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="">
                    <h3>Desert Safari</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81z07Nvam1L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="">
                    <h3>Desert Safari</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81z07Nvam1L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="">
                    <h3>Desert Safari</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to link each box to different link. whole box not only content or image so if user try to click any of these will be sent to the link applied .
i have tried putting a tag on these box but my box color changes and things go wrong.
need help pls

Comment: If `<a>` tags don’t work for you, you can change the `location.href` on click with JavaScript. You could also change the box tag from `div` to `a` and apply `display: block` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is applying styles that need to be applied to the direct child of `.container` to divs inside `<a>` tags. You can replace the `<div>`s with `<a>`s.

```css
.container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
}
.container .box{
    position: relative;
    width: 33.33%; /*Change Applied*/
    height: 500px;
    background: #ccc;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .box:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.container .box .thumb{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container .box:nth-child(odd) .thumb {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.container .box .thumb img{
    width: 100%;
}
.container .box .details{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #262626;
}
.container .box:nth-child(even) .details {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.container .box:nth-child(1) .details {
    background: #65214a;
}
.container .box:nth-child(2) .details {
    background: #fd3f41;
}
.container .box:nth-child(3) .details {
    background: #ffb539;
}
.container .box .details .content{
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% + 16px);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .box:hover .details .content{
    top: calc(50%);
}
.container .box .details .content h3{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="activity.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="box">
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81z07Nvam1L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="">
                    <h3>Desert Safari</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="box">
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81z07Nvam1L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="">
                    <h3>Desert Safari</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="box">
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81z07Nvam1L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="">
                    <h3>Desert Safari</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry, I didn’t see it while creating the fiddle.

Comment: It's ok - I see YOU said something similar 3 minutes before my post in a comment

Comment: thanks ,other answer might be right but this one has complete my need . thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the div class="box" to `<a class="box"` then you could style the link

Otherwise use JavaScript:

```js
const links = ["https://www.apple.com/us/search/mac", "https://www.apple.com/us/search/iphone", "https://www.apple.com/us/search/ipad"];
document.querySelectorAll(".container .box").forEach((box, i) => box.dataset.idx = i);
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest(".box");
  if (tgt) {
    location = links[tgt.dataset.idx]
  }  
})
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
}

.container .box {
  position: relative;
  width: 33.33%;
  /*Change Applied*/
  height: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.container .box .thumb {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .box:nth-child(odd) .thumb {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container .box .thumb img {
  width: 100%;
}

.container .box .details {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #262626;
}

.container .box:nth-child(even) .details {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container .box:nth-child(1) .details {
  background: #65214a;
}

.container .box:nth-child(2) .details {
  background: #fd3f41;
}

.container .box:nth-child(3) .details {
  background: #ffb539;
}

.container .box .details .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% + 16px);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .box:hover .details .content {
  top: calc(50%);
}

.container .box .details .content h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="activity.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81z07Nvam1L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <div class="content">
          <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="">
          <h3>Desert Safari</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81z07Nvam1L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <div class="content">
          <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="">
          <h3>Desert Safari</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81z07Nvam1L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <div class="content">
          <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="">
          <h3>Desert Safari</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for answering and showing alternative way . thank you for your time

Answer (score -3):

You can use "a" tag like this:

```
<a href="<your_link>">
   <your content>
</a>
```

Comment: thanks for providing a answer.